# VSC discord bot event locking

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Hi I Coded A Bot But I Want To limit Bot's One Exact Event in One Channel This is Code
No Errors Just Need To *Lock* This Event in one channel

````
module.exports = async (client, message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return
    if (message.channel.type === "dm") {
        const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("736112465678565437")
        const channel = guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === "modmail-messages")
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor(`${message.author.tag} | ${message.author.id}`, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
        .addField("Message", message.content)
        .setFooter("Sent")
        .setTimestamp()
        .setColor("PURPLE")
        await message.author.send("Sending To Staff...")
        await channel.send(embed)
    }
    if (message.channel.type !== "dm" && message.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === "modmail-messages")) {
        const user = message.mentions.members.first()
        const args = message.content.slice(process.env.PREFIX.length).trim().split(/ +/g)
        let response = args.slice(1).join(' ')
        if (!response)
            return message.reply("please provide a response to the user!")
        if (!user)
            return message.reply("please specify a user!")
        await user.send(`**(•Hyper Staff)** ${message.member.displayName}: ${response}`)
    }
    if (message.content.indexOf(process.env.PREFIX) !== 0) return
    const args = message.content.slice(process.env.PREFIX.length).trim().split(/ +/g)
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase()
    const cmd = client.commands.get(command)
    if (!cmd) return 
    cmd.run(client, message, args)
}```
````

Comment: Please read over [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question :)

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean by "locking the event in one channel"? You want the bot to send a message in a specific channel?

Comment: Yes Only In One Channel But Only This Event

Comment: Yeah, your code already finds the channel and sends a message there.

Comment: Yes It Does but if i dont mention user it sends Please Mention user

Comment: That's intended? You have told the code to do that.

Comment: How did you code it yourself if YOU don't understand YOUR code?

Comment: i really need help

Comment: You need help with? Help us understand.